# Datagrid cells empty but correct amount of rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that I can populate with the correct amount of rows, but the actual cells are blank. I am trying to bind the values of an enum to the datagrid.

I've read multiple articles about properties and fields being the cause of this but as far as I can tell, I'm doing it like them but still not getting anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class logLevelString {  
    public logLevelString(string nameParam) { 
        this.name = nameParam;
    }
    string name { get; set;}
}


private void UserControl_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    List<logLevelString> strings = new List<logLevelString>();
    List<String> logLevels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ISysEvent.eventLogLevel)).ToList();
    foreach (string currentString in logLevels) {  
        strings.Add(new logLevelString(currentString));
    }
    dgEventViewerOptions.ItemsSource = strings;
}
```

Do I have to mention the ItemsSource in the xaml file too? If so how do I reference it?

I'm still very new to WPF and there's a lot to get my head around!

Xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WRMS_BaseLibraryUI.UI_UserControl.WDL_Event.ucEventViewerOptions"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="297" d:DesignWidth="215" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgEventViewerOptions" RowHeight="15"     FontSize="11" />
    <Label Content="Data:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,92,0,0" Name="lblDataSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" MinWidth="200" />
    <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,116,0,159" Name="txtDataSearch" Width="200" MinWidth="200" />
    <Label Content="Text:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,139,0,0" Name="lblTextSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" MinWidth="200" />
    <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,164,0,0" Name="txtTextSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" MinWidth="200" />

    <Button Content="Search" Margin="12,241,12,12" Name="btnSearch" Click="btnSearch_Click" />
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: you need to show us your xaml code too. Show us where you bind your List to your control. Also you can check the output window in visual studio for binding errors.

Comment: added, can't see anything in the output window relating to that. Relating to binding the list the control, is it not done on this line "dgEventOptions.ItemsSource = strings;"?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to make the `name` property public and not set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` on the DataGrid. Then you should also follow widely accepted coding rules and use Pascal casing for public identifiers like class and property names:

```
class LogLevel
{
    public LogLevel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could simplify the code that creates your data items:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ISysEvent.eventLogLevel));
var levels = names.Select(n => new LogLevel(n));

dgEventViewerOptions.ItemsSource = levels;
```

---

That said, there is still no data binding involved (except the binding done internally by the DataGrid). In order to use data binding you would have to create a view model class with a public property that returns a collection of LogLevel objects, and bind (in XAML) the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` to that property.

Start reading the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.